# Ubuntu Core rotate screen Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: screen, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

The display on my Ubuntu Core, latest version (18), on a Raspberry Pi 3 is upside down. The display is connected via the ribbon cable on the Pi, not via HDMI.

I first tried via the [system snap config](https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/reference/core-configuration) (restarted the system each time).

```
snap set pi-config.display-rotate=2
snap set pi-config.lcd-rotate=2 (does not work, unsupported system option)
```

I tried values 1, 2, and 3. Setting `pi-config.display-rotate=1` and rebooting shows a white display but the Pi doesn't boot, a power reset was needed to get it booted.

I also tried via the [config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) (writable partition: `system-data/boot/config.txt`). Took the SD card out, edited the file on another computer and restarted the Pi each time (tried values 0, 1, 2, and 3).

```
display_rotate=2
lcd_rotate=2
```

The screen doesn't budge. It never changes the rotation. Editing the `boot.txt` on [Retropi](https://retropie.org.uk/) (same hardware) did work correctly. Is there a special way to rotate the screen on Ubuntu Core?

Just so I understand this correctly: the "Core" logo and text (where it shows the login via SSH instructions) is upside down. I have no Wayland or X11 running. Maybe I misunderstand this and the screen is only supposed to turn in a graphical environment?

Comment: Just curious who and where have recommended you to use `snap set pi-config...`? Why do you think that this way is supported?

Comment: @N0rbert I found that option in the Snapcraft [system options documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/system-options#heading--pi-config). Why do you ask? Am I not supposed to change that setting?

Comment: I have never seen this before. Looks great. Thank you. Will try to use it on my RPi4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work the correct way, not the workaround described in my [other](https://askubuntu.com/a/1293464/1127506) answer.

1. There are 2 display connectors on the Raspberry Pi board: the *HDMI* and *display* ports. The HDMI is the one with the HDMI plug (easy enough), the display one is where you connect the ribbon cable. I am using the ribbon cable. Changing the HDMI settings doesn't change a thing, I needed the `lcd_rotate` setting which is the one rotating the display, not the HDMI screen! :facepalm:

```bsh
lcd_rotate=2 # rotates the screen connected to the display port
display_hdmi_rotate=2 # rotates the screen connected to the HDMI port
display_lcd_rotate=2 # no idea what screen this applies to
```

2. The second mistake was to edit the wrong config.txt file. I was editing a config.txt in the `writable/system-data/boot` or `writable/system-data/boot/uboot` directories but that's NOT where Ubuntu Core looks. The config.txt file is located in the other partition on the SD card, in the root of the `system-boot` partition!

Comment: Care to share the exact location you edited? asking for a ~n00b~ friend ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a third way which works, via mir-kiosk. I think this solution is more resource-intensive than the options above, so **first try the ones in my original question** above. The top ones are hardware-based, this is software-based if I understand correctly.

Install the mir-kiosk snap if you haven't yet and edit the `/var/snap/mir-kiosk/current/miral-kiosk.display` configuration. I appended the following:

```yml
  inverted:
    cards:
    - card-id: 0
      DSI-1:
        orientation: inverted
```

Now update the display layout configuration setting in mir-kiosk:

```bsh
$ snap set mir-kiosk display-layout=inverted
```

The mir-kiosk snap will restart and… the screen is inverted!

This solution has a drawback though, the Ubuntu Core logo will still be upside down when the Raspberry boots since the display flipping only happens when mir-kiosk boots. It also only works if you are using mir-kiosk so I would still like to understand why the boot.txt option doesn't work (edit: I found the solution, check the [other](https://askubuntu.com/a/1304524/1127506) answer).